# Single row selected as multiple rows in sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not expert of writing sql queries. I have currently come up with a stored procedure. The stored procedure was working fine when I haven't applied inner join. I have two tables.

Table 1: Product
Table 2: ProductRating

The stored procedure was used to select the records page wise. I have created this by consulting an online article. The body of stored procedure is mentioned below,

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PostedDate] Desc)AS RowNumber,[Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate], 
           ISNULL(AVG([ProductRating].[RatingValue]), 0) AverageRating, COUNT([Rating].[RatingValue]) RatingCount
           INTO #DealResults1
           FROM [Products]
           LEFT OUTER  JOIN [Rating] ON [Product].[Id] = [Rating].[ProductId]
           WHERE [City] = CASE WHEN @CityId IS NULL THEN [City] ELSE @CityId END 
           AND [Description] IS NOT NULL  
           Group by [Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate], [Rating].[RatingValue]
           ORDER BY [PostedDate] Desc


           DECLARE @RecordCount1 INT
           SELECT @RecordCount1 = COUNT(*) FROM #ProductResults1

           SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount1 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
           PRINT @PageCount

           SELECT * FROM #ProductResults1
           WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

           DROP TABLE #ProductResults1
```

Now I admit that I am very poor when it comes to joins and I never completely understand the Group by.

Problem Statement:
When the user rate a product a record is inserted each time in the Rating table. Now if the user rate Product1 three times then Product is selected three times. Sometimes two times. I don't understand this problem. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Probably the `PostedDate` column belongs to the Rating table and you are using it into the `GROUP BY`clause. Therefore it will repeat the products by the rating, since you have different date/time...

Comment: group by only columns from product table. you are adding [Rating].[RatingValue] in group by. example: Group by [Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate]

Comment: Thank you both. Yes @Sandeep you are right after removing [Rating].[RatingValue] from Group By the problem is solved now. I will study about it more to understand it. If you could post it as an answer then I will be able to mark it as answer. Kindly if you could add couple of line describing this behaviour. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group by only columns from product table. you are adding [Rating].[RatingValue] in group by. 
example:

```
Group by [Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate]
```